# trying to use WebForm (ASPX) login page with MVC 3 app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, webforms, single-sign-on, siteminder

I have a technical requirement to start from a "public" (non-secure) physical ASPX page and then bridge into an MVC 3 application.  I have figured out the changes to "routing", but the MVC [Authorize] does not seem to recognize that the user (cookie) is authenticated.  It keeps taking me back to the ASPX login page.

Has anyone successfully used a standard, physcial page as login, and then transfer into secure MVC? This is part of a larger SSO design effort.